# how did to make Swipe slideshow without any plugins or other?

Tags: jquery, html, css

how to make swipe image slideshow with `css` and `Jquery` that when i swipe screen right to left the image is change. that this is work on computer and mobile screen?

Comment: Hi David, welcome to stack overflow. You should consider searching on Google for a tutorial. This one looks allright: https://medium.com/@fionnachan/how-to-write-a-slider-in-pure-javascript-838c0d98fd69 . You should post questions here if you have more specific questions :)

Comment: hi @raz0rwire, i searching but not founding anything. 
others use swiper.js or other plugins and dont make with pure css and jquery!

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo for a slider.

**check the snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
    $('#checkbox').change(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            moveRight();
        }, 3000);
    });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({
        width: slideWidth,
        height: slideHeight
    });

    $('#slider ul').css({
        width: sliderUlWidth,
        marginLeft: -slideWidth
    });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: +slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: -slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });
});
```

```css
 html {
    border-top: 5px solid #fff;
    background: #58DDAF;
    color: #2a2a2a;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:'Open Sans';
}
h1 {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#slider {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#slider ul {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 200px;
    list-style: none;
}
#slider ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
}
a.control_prev, a.control_next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
    padding: 4% 3%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background: #2a2a2a;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
a.control_prev {
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
a.control_next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
.slider_option {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 160px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Incredibly Basic Slider</h1>

<div id="slider">
    <a href="#" class="control_next">&gt;</a>
    <a href="#" class="control_prev">&lt;</a>
    <ul>
        <li>SLIDE 1</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
        <li>SLIDE 3</li>
        <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="slider_option">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
    <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but this not drag image to go next image!
and
this slideshow when select autoplay and then diselect that. the imge change twice!!!:) ;)